# Determining if stdout for a Python process is redirected

Tags: python, io-redirection

I've noticed that curl can tell whether or not I'm redirecting its output (in which case it puts up a progress bar).

Is there a reasonable way to do this in a Python script?  So:

```
$ python my_script.py
Not redirected
```

and

```
$ python my_script.py > output.txt  
Redirected!
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, what you want to do here is find out if `stdin` and `stdout` are the same thing.

```
$ cat test.py
import os
print(os.fstat(0) == os.fstat(1))
$ python test.py
True
$ python test.py > f
$ cat f
False
$
```

The longer but more traditional version of the *are they the same file* test just compares `st_ino` and `st_dev`. Typically, on windows these are faked up with a hash of something so that this exact design pattern will work.

Comment: Since this works on Windows I think it's what I want.

Note that this approach *won't* work if I do:  
$ echo "blah" | python test.py

Comment: This tells you if either stdin OR stdout have been redirected.
`echo foo | python test.py` will also result in "False" as an output.

Answer (score 49):

```
import sys

if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print("Not redirected")
else:
    sys.stderr.write("Redirected!\n")
```

Comment: There is a catch on Windows: if a stream is redirected to nul, `isatty` still returns True.

Answer (score 4):

Look at

```
os.isatty(fd)
```

(I don't think this works on Windows, however)